# Thread freezes when trying to wait for callback

Tags: android, kotlin

i am trying to  interrupt a for-loop with a endless running while-loop till the `Callback onSuccess` changes the condition and the while-loop is exited, like so:

```
for(distance in FocusDistances){
                settingFocus = true
                Log.d(TAG, "setting focus to $distance")
                var captureRequestOptions = CaptureRequestOptions.Builder()
                    .setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF)
                    .setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE, distance).build()

                Camera2CameraControl.from(camera!!.cameraControl).captureRequestOptions =
                    captureRequestOptions

                var listenableFuture = Camera2CameraControl.from(camera!!.cameraControl)
                    .setCaptureRequestOptions(captureRequestOptions)
                Futures.addCallback(listenableFuture, object : FutureCallback<Void> {
                    override fun onSuccess(result: Void?) {
                        settingFocus = false
                        captureImage(imageCapture)
                        Log.d(TAG, "focus set!")
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(t: Throwable?) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Failed setting Focus ${t!!.message}")
                    }
                }, context!!.mainExecutor)

                while(settingFocus){
                    continue
                }
            }
        }
```

My problem is that while-loop starts befor the callback is able to complete and when the while-loop is running everything freezes and nothing else is executed. i dont get any callback back and that loop runs for ever.

Could someone give me some advise how to correct this ?

My actual goal is to take a number of pictures at differnt focal length. for that i want to set focus, when focus set a picture should be taken and only when the picture gets saved it should continue with the next picture at a different focal length.

thanks in advance

Comment: Remove the while loop. If you want something to happen after your results are ready, put that code inside your FutureCallback. If you don't want to use coroutines, then you'll probably want to break this code out into a function that recursively calls itself in the callback, or create all your tasks up front before running them in sequence. Coroutines would enable much simpler code, but they are not a trivial subject to jump into.

Comment: thanks a lot. will try to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate approach is to use [`ListenableFuture.await()`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-guava/kotlinx.coroutines.guava/await.html).